# Any way to use brushless ESCs to drive 4 wire bipolar stepper motor?

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, motor-controller

I have some brushless ESCs, Arduino, and Raspberry Pi lying around, and I'm wondering if there's some way to use this combination to drive a 4 wire bipolar stepper motor.

Comment: No. They have different hardware even if you could change the firmware (which you would need to). A brushless ESC has three half-bridges. A bipolar motor requires two H-bridges (or four half-bridges since two half-bridges make an H-bridge). That means that two bidirecitonal DC brushed motor drivers could conceivably drive a 4-wire bipolar stepper if you controlled them properly.

Comment: I actually have 2 or 3 brushed ESCs. Thanks for the suggestion. Could you elaborate on how to control them? My intuition suggests to connect each to a pole, then run current in either direction. I think forward pole 1, forward pole 2, reverse pole 1, reverse pole 2, repeat.

Comment: You can just Google that. I don't know the firing sequence but there's only one real way to wire things up when I told you that you need two H-bridges and you know the bipolar stepper only has two coils. The purpose of an H-bridge is to let you send current through a load in two directions. So four different possible combinations of current flowing through the two coils.

Comment: I found this and based my now amended comment on it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAyDmovM18E

Comment: You’d be so much better off with a dedicated stepper driver. Jerry rigging some ESC’s sounds like a difficult and error prone way to solve a problem.

Comment: Yes. Sell on eBay, use the proceeds to buy a stepper driver.

Comment: I tried the mentioned approach, effectively copying the stepper library, and ended up with an oscillating and rapidly heating motor. Any suggestions?